# Messed Up By Changing Username using netplwiz on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, administrator

I MESSED UP MAJORLY BY CHANGING THE USERNAME OF MY ADMIN (THE ONLY ACC I USE) using netplwiz nd now I’m constantly getting the message “No Mapping between account names and Security Id was done” whenever I try to do anything.

I haven’t restarted my PC yet because I’m afraid it might make things worse. I’m considering backing up the stuff inside the user folder in C:/Users/olduser. However, I don’t see the new username there.

Is it possible to revert this change? Like, can I go back to the old username by logging into the administrator account or creating a new account with admin privileges?

Also, how can I ensure that I can access the old user folder through other user accounts in case I mess something up?

I have never used or touched the Windows repair tool and I never set it up or backed up my stuff. I have no clue how it works;

I found this https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/what-is-meant-by-no-mapping-between-account-names/dcccb1bb-1c4d-4bd5-91a7-832cabf9c86b ; this says just to back things up; which Im doing rn;

I'm rly worried because I have a lot of important folders on the desktop which are inside the OLDUSER folder... :(

PS: IF I wanna take a complete backup of the OLDUSER folder to another drive, simply copying it over using ctrl +c would suffice? Even with all the protected nd hidden folders nd symlinks?

When Im trying to copy certain files; [esp from appdata] it says permission denied or file open by X; what can I do about that?

Comment: The only thing I can suggest (and I do not know the consequences in your case) is to temporarily enable the disable Administrator Account.  Log in, make a new admin user and then log in as that and see if you can recover your documents.     ......   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/windows-security/access-computer-after-administrator-disabled

Comment: Enable the built-in Administrator and change your username back to it’s original name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can still start a command prompt as administrator, here is the safest way to get things working again:

From a command prompt ran as administrator, type the following:

```
net user NewUser * /add
```

type a new password (or enter to not set one)

```
net localgroup Administrators /add NewUser
```

You now created a new administrator user.

Press start, useraccounts and select switch user. Don't log off or restart, switch user.

Switch to the new NewUser user and verify that you can do things as admin and that the account works. (if your computer is domain-joined, type `.\NewUser` as the username)

After you verify that you can work in this account, you can press start, switch user, and go back to your main user. It is now safe to log off this user.

After the broken user is logged off, switch back to your working NewUser, and fix your broken user from there, for example by running netplwiz again to rename it back.

Test that everything works, and when satisfied that your problem is resolved, you can remove the user from command prompt, by running:

```
net user /delete NewUser
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Comment: You're welcome. :)